# Error when try to add metadata to file in Sharepoint with MSGraph v6 for Java

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a file in sharepoint (I know the DriveItemId) and I would like to add metadata (let's say, title) to it. I'm using MS Graph SDK for Java (6.3.0) for that purpose. I try to do it like this:

```
GraphServiceClient client = .... ;
Map<String, Object> metadata=... ;
...    
final DriveItem driveItem = client.drives().byDriveId(<parent_folder_id>).items().byDriveItemId(driveItemId).get();
driveItem.setAdditionalData(metadata);
client.drives().byDriveId(<parent_folder_id>).items().byDriveItemId(driveItemId).patch(driveItem);
```

But I've got error when execute "patch":

```
com.microsoft.graph.models.odataerrors.ODataError: Invalid request
    at com.microsoft.graph.models.odataerrors.ODataError.createFromDiscriminatorValue(ODataError.java:36)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.getObjectValue(JsonParseNode.java:210)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.http.OkHttpRequestAdapter.lambda$throwIfFailedResponse$0(OkHttpRequestAdapter.java:672)
```

Are there any other ways to achieve that?

Comment: What kind of metadata do you want add/update?

Comment: Accutaly I'm trying to update title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to update `fields` on a `listItem` associated with a `driveItem`

```
// get the listItem associated with the driveItem
final ListItem listItem = graphClient.drives().byDriveId("").items().byDriveItemId("").listItem().get(e -> e.queryParameters.select = new String[] { "sharepointids" });

// prepare fieldValueSet to be updated
FieldValueSet fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet();
HashMap<String, Object> additionalData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
additionalData.put("Title", "New value");
fieldValueSet.setAdditionalData(additionalData);

// read sharepoint ids
SharepointIds sharepointIds = listItem.getSharepointIds();
    
// update fields of the listItem associated with the driveItem
graphClient.sites().bySiteId(sharepointIds.getSiteId()).lists().byListId(sharepointIds.getListId()).items().byListItemId(sharepointIds.getListItemId()).fields().patch(fieldValueSet);
```

Comment: This was very promising but I've got exception 'The specified list was not found'

Comment: @PastorPL my bad, list id is part of SharepointIds. Check updated answer

Comment: I've found out that your solution is missing 2 tings: 
 1. In first line you need to "select" sharepointids: listItem().get(e -> e.queryParameters.select = new String[] { "sharepointids" }); 
 2. We should use this sharepointids to get listItemId in last line: byListItemId(sharepointIds.getListItemId()). 
 Please update and I will accept the answer :)
 BTW. Could you be so kind and reveal your source of knowledge about MS Graph? :) I've tried with oficial docs but it was hard, are there any other docs / tutorials / articles?

Comment: @PastorPL Code updated. Source of knowledge? The doc, github issues https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib/issues, experience from my work,...